# How to understand the creation of a singly linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

### Problem

I have some difficulties in understanding the code (not the meaning) of a tutorial to create a singly linked list with c++.

### Code

```
typedef int ElemType;   
struct Node{
    ElemType data;
    Node *next;
};

class LinkList{
private:
    Node *Head;
public:
    LinkList();         
    ~LinkList();
    void CreateList1(int n);
    void CreateList2(int n);
    void ListInsert(int i, int e);
    int ListDelete(int i);
    int GetElem(int i);
    int LocateElem(int e);
    int ListLength();
};

void LinkList::CreateList1(int n) {
    //create a linked list by inserting the element in the head
    Node *p, *s;
    p = Head;
    cout<<"请依次输入"<<n<<"个数据元素值"<<endl;
    for (int i =1; i<n; i++){
        s = new Node;           
        cin>>s->data;
        s->next=p->next;       
        p->next=s;              // what does it mean? I don't get it.
    }
}

void LinkList::CreateList2(int n) {
    //create a linked list by inserting the element in the end
    Node *p, *s;
    p = Head;
    cout << "请依次输入" << n << "个数据元素值" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        s = new Node;          
        cin >> s->data;
        p->next=s;              
        p=s;                   // what does it mean? I don't get it.
    }
}
```

### Note

The code snippet that I do not understand is commented. Anyone can explain the code with instructive words or figures? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is the pointer to the insertion point.

The new node is inserted AFTER `p`.

In the first case, `p->next=s`, we hang the new node `s` off the node pointed to by `p`, but `p` itself does not change. The next node will still be inserted right after `Head`.

In the second case, `p->next=s` is still done, but then we do `p=s`, so the insertion point `p` moves to the last element of the list, `s`. The next node will be inserted at the end of the list, not at the head.

Comment: Thank you. In the 1st case, the snippet `p->next=s` has changed the `p`, doesn't it? Does it mean assign the memory address of `s` to `p->next` ? I still do not understand why `p` remains unchanged.

Comment: p->next is not p. Assignment to p->next changes the contents of the node p is pointing to, not p itself.

Comment: In the next iteration, `p->next` is not the address of the head, and `p->next` is assigned to `s->next`. Then why does the head node still point to the new `s`?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between changing the pointer and changing the thing it points to.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood these two meanings. So in this case, the `P` it self has not been changed all the time while the things it points to has been changed in each iteration. Is that right?

Comment: "The thing it points to is changed" is a bit ambiguous language, be careful. But, yes, the contents of the record that p is pointing at is changed (in particular, the `next` field of that record. p itself keeps pointing at the same record.

Answer (score 1):

This: `[ ]` is a node and: `->` is used to show where the node points to.

### 1st case:

- `HEAD` will point to the `new node`
- the `new node` will point where `HEAD` was previously pointing

> ```
> p->next=s;              // what does it mean? I don't get it
> ```
>
> It means: `HEAD` should now point to the `new node`

---

```
[HEAD]->

iteration 1:
-------------------------------
s = new Node      : [S1]
s->next = p->next : [S1]->
p->next = s       : [HEAD]->[S1]

iteration 2:
-------------------------------
s = new Node      : [S2]
s->next = p->next : [S2]->[S1]
p->next = s       : [HEAD]->[S2]->[S1]

iteration 3:
-------------------------------
s = new Node      : [S3]
s->next = p->next : [S3]->[S2]
p->next = s       : [HEAD]->[S3]->[S2]->[S1]
```

### 2nd case:

- `HEAD` will point to the `new node`
- The `new node` becomes `HEAD`

> ```
> p=s;              // what does it mean? I don't get it
> ```
>
> It means: the `new node` now also becomes `HEAD`

---

```
[HEAD]->

iteration 1:
-------------------------------
s = new Node      : [S1]
p->next = s       : [HEAD]->[S1]
p = s             : [HEAD,S1]               // S1 is the HEAD now

iteration 2:
-------------------------------
s = new Node      : [S2]
p->next = s       : [HEAD,S1]->[S2]
p = s             : [S1]->[HEAD,S2]        // S2 is the HEAD now

iteration 3:
-------------------------------
s = new Node      : [S3]
p->next = s       : [HEAD,S2]->[S3]
p = s             : [S1]->[S2]->[HEAD,S3]  // S3 is the HEAD now
```

Comment: `s = new Node;          
        cin>>s->data;
        s->next=p->next;       
        p->next=s;`

Comment: Thank you friend. In the 1st case, the latter two lines in the iteration above means the head will point to S, but then S is assigned to p->next. Then in the next iteration, head does not point to P because the previous S changes the memory address of P, and `s->next=p->next` in the next iteration no longer means the same as first iteration does. What is wrong with my idea?